# Asymptote for $\frac{\sum _{j=1}^x \text{frac}\left(\frac{x}{j}\right)}{x}$?

Tags: summation, asymptotics, average, fractional-part

I have been noodling around with the function

$$f(x):=\frac{\sum _{j=1}^x \text{frac}\left(\frac{x}{j}\right)}{x}$$

where $x$ is a positive integer, and $\text{frac}(n)$ denotes the fractional part of $n$. I initially thought that $f$ would be asymptotic to $x=\frac{x}{2}$ since for large $x$ each of the possible values

$$\text{frac}\left(\frac{x}{j}\right)=\left\{0,\frac{1}{j},\frac{2}{j},\ldots ,\frac{j-1}{j}\right\}$$

should occur with equal probability. However, my assumption is clearly wrong. Heuristically, the asymptote is in fact something like $x=\frac{21}{50}$, as the plot below shows.

Can someone please explain why?

[image]

Comment: When you write $\sum_{j=1}^x$ do you mean $\sum_{j=1}^{\lfloor x \rfloor}$? Or are you looking at integer $x$?

Comment: Hi @Ian. My bad. I meant integer x. I'll update the OP.

Comment: Word of advice, just because $x$ can represent an integer, I'd caution against. It is a useful convention to represent integers with $m,n,i,j,k$, real numbers with $x,y,z$, complex ones with $z,u,w$ etc. Most people will assume $x$ is a real number.

Comment: Doing some histograms, I find that there is a distinct bias to the left in the distribution of the fractional parts. This persists even when the integer in question is prime (so that $0$ only appears once).

Comment: Use $\displaystyle \left\{\cdots\right\}$ instead of $\displaystyle\mathrm{frac}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the known asymptotics of the harmonic numbers and the divisor summatory function, we have
\begin{align*}
\sum\limits_{j = 1}^x {\left\{ {\frac{x}{j}} \right\}} & = \sum\limits_{j = 1}^x {\frac{x}{j}}  - \sum\limits_{j = 1}^x {\left\lfloor {\frac{x}{j}} \right\rfloor }   = x\sum\limits_{j = 1}^x {\frac{1}{j}}  - \sum\limits_{j = 1}^x {d(j)} \\ & = x\left( {\log x + \gamma  + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{x}} \right)} \right) - x\log x - x(2\gamma  - 1) + \mathcal{O}(\sqrt x ) \\ & = x(1-\gamma)+\mathcal{O}(\sqrt x ).
\end{align*}
Thus
$$
\frac{1}{x}\sum\limits_{j = 1}^x {\left\{ {\frac{x}{j}} \right\}}  = 1 - \gamma  + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{\sqrt x }}} \right).
$$
This shows that the limit is $1-\gamma =0.4227843350\ldots$.

Comment: $d\left(j\right) ?$.

Comment: $d(j)$ denotes the number of divisors of $j$.

Comment: $\displaystyle +1$. Thanks. Nice answer.

Answer (score 0):

The asymptotic value is actually $1-\gamma \approx 0.4228$ , where $\gamma$ is [Euler's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant)

See [here](https://www.dmg.tuwien.ac.at/nfn/gamma.pdf) (I actually got this result, before finding this paper, by a not-so-rigorous probabilistic approach).